# Deal with associations using ember-cli and ember-localstorage-adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-local-storage

Maybe it's a stupid question but I am in the middle (hopefully) of the ember learning curve. My application uses ember-localstorage-adapter and some of my models has associations.

After saving few records, the ember inspector show me that all regular attributes are saved in the LocalStorage but cannot find a way to save the relationship among them. I think it has something to do with serializers but I was not able to find anything that explain how to store (and the use to retrieve) some kind of external keys.

Am I missing something big?

Comment: jsbin demonstration wold be helpful

Comment: You are right @Artych but reproduce an ember-cli app in a jsbin is not that easy, for me at least. After some investigation I found out the problem was not storing the associations but retrieving them. The fact I cannot see them is probably due to [this bug](https://github.com/kurko/ember-localstorage-adapter/issues/68#issuecomment-111967686). As you can see from my comment I solved with a workaround, not a real solution